# Edit layout of Magento 1.9 CE Shopping Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, edit, shopping

In the attached image of my site's shopping cart, how do I edit the header so that the headers are over the correct columns? Magento 1.9 CE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml

find below code

```
<th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Product') ?></span></th>
```

Just after that add one extra `<th>`

```
<th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">&nbsp;</th>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying so quickly! I'm very new to Magento, so just to be clear, do I edit app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml or app/design/frontend/melt/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml

Comment: 'Melt' is the name of our company

Comment: Hi, I edited the file as you suggested in app/design/frontend/melt/default/template/checkout/cart.phtm‌​l and it has fixed the problem. Thanks so much for your help!